# Deleted ubuntu partition, re-partitioned it into an E: drive, now grub rescue

Tags: linux, windows-8, multi-boot

I used the Windows Disk Management to delete the ubuntu partition, then re-partition the old space as an E: drive on the windows system. Now when I try to boot, I get an unknown filesystem error, then grub rescue starts.

I can get into windows using an Ubuntu OS drive I have and loading grub through it to boot windows, but how can I repair the computer so that I can boot windows without needing to use this flash drive?

Comment: Repair the windows Bootloader.  This cannot be accomplished without a windows ISO

Comment: How would I go about doing that? I have the windows install disk, if that would be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Ubuntu LiveUSB to repair your bootloader..

Just boot using the live USB, not the other drive with Ubuntu, then install boot-repair, hit the fix button and it should be OK after the reboot..

You can download boot-repair using:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Take a look at the [wiki page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) to get more details about boot-repair usage

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you installed GRUB on first partition of your hard disk, instead of same partition you installed Ubuntu on.

Follow these steps to fix your MBR and restore Windows Bootloader.

1. Boot into Windows installation disk.
2. Select language.
3. At System Recovery Options screen, select Command Prompt.
4. Execute these command in sequence:

> bootrec /fixmbr
>
> bootrec /fixboot
>
> bootrec /ScanOs
>
> bootrec /rebuildBcd

5. Close Command Prompt and reboot.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem trying to end a dual-boot and go back to just Windows. Not sure how specific this is to how I originally installed the dual-boot, but I was able to reset to use the Windows boot loader by accessing the BIOS menu during setup, then going to Boot > Boot Device Priority and resetting Boot Option #1 to Windows Boot Manager and disabling Boot Option #2.